# PowerShell - Find files larger than 2 GB and convert them into 2 GB Split files

Tags: powershell, 7zip

OK, so I'm new to powershell and i searched a lot to make a script that can do the title work for me, So far so now i managed  to find files but after cant convert them into zips. The powershell compress-archive don't have split functionality maybe, so i found 7zip4shell and make script something like this, but it not working, hope u guys can help me out.

```
Get-ChildItem "E:\Folder 1\Folder 2\My Files with sub folders" -recurse | where-object {$_.length -gt 2147483648} | ForEach-Object {Compress-7Zip -Path . -VolumeSize 2093796556 -ArchiveFileName "$($_.Name).zip"}
```

Ok so this script is giving me error about some random path (not the files path), that access is denied.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the [OpenWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite?view=net-7.0#system-io-file-openwrite(system-string)) method, from the **System.IO** class:

```
$maxFileSize = 2GB
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.Length -gt $maxFileSize }

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $numSplits = [math]::Ceiling($file.Length / $maxFileSize)
    #Create a folder to save the splitted files
    $splitDirectory = Join-Path -Path $file.Directory.FullName -ChildPath ($file.BaseName + "_splits")
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $splitDirectory | Out-Null
    # Split the file into 2 GB chunks
    $offset = 0
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $numSplits; $i++) {
        $splitFilePath = Join-Path -Path $splitDirectory -ChildPath ($file.BaseName + "_split$i" + $file.Extension)
        $length = [Math]::Min($maxFileSize, $file.Length - $offset)
        $buffer = New-Object byte[] $length
        $stream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($file.FullName)
        $stream.Seek($offset, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin)
        $stream.Read($buffer, 0, $length)
        $stream.Close()
        $outputStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite($splitFilePath)
        $outputStream.Write($buffer, 0, $length)
        $outputStream.Close()
        $offset += $length
    }
}
```

And split like this:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

I think Victor's code looks great, but I offer a function to split a target file into chunks of any size with an optional switch to zip the chunks up. For the sake of making sure it works, I include another function to join the files back together and demonstrate that the rejoined file hash matches the original file hash. (FWIW I confirmed Victor's rejoined hash is good as well.)

```
function Split-File () {
    param (
        [string]$InputPath,
        [int]$ChunkSize = 1024*1024,
        [switch]$Zip
    )

    if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($InputPath)) {
        Write-Host "File does not exist" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        return
    }
    

    $file = Get-Item -Path $InputPath

    if ($file.Length -le $ChunkSize) {
        Write-Host "File does not need to be chunked for size $ChunkSize" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        return $null
    }


    $numChunks = [math]::Ceiling($file.Length / $ChunkSize)
    #Write-Host "Number of chunks = $numChunks for file size $($file.Length) and chunk size $ChunkSize"
    $chunkedFiles = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
    try {
        $readStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($InputPath,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
        $reader = [System.IO.BinaryReader]::new($readStream)
        $position = 0
        $buffer = 1024
        for($i = 0; $i -lt $numChunks; $i++) {
            $newFile = Join-Path $file.Directory "$($file.BaseName)_$($i + 1)$($file.Extension)"
            Write-Host $newFile -ForegroundColor Cyan
            try {
                $writeStream  = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($newFile,[System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate)
                $writer = [System.IO.BinaryWriter]::new($writeStream)
                for($j = $position; $j -lt ($position + $ChunkSize); $j += $buffer) {
                    $bytes = $reader.ReadBytes($buffer)
                    $writer.Write($bytes)
                }
                $position = $j + 1
                $chunkedFiles.Add($newFile)
            } catch {
                Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
            } finally {
                $writer.Close()
                $writer.Dispose()
                $writeStream.Close()
                $writeStream.Dispose()
            }
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    } finally {
        $reader.Close()
        $reader.Dispose()
        $readStream.Close()
        $readStream.Dispose()
    }

    if ($Zip) {
        $zipFileName = "$($InputPath)_chunked.zip"
        Compress-Archive -Path $chunkedFiles.ToArray() -DestinationPath $zipFileName
    }
}




function Join-Files([string[]]$Files, [string]$OutputPath) {
    foreach($file in $Files) {
        if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($file)) {
            Write-Host "File does not exist: $file" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            return
        }
    }

    try {
        $writeStream  = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($OutputPath,[System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate)
        $writer = [System.IO.BinaryWriter]::new($writeStream)
        foreach($item in $Files) {
            try {
                $file = Get-Item $item
                $readStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($file.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
                $reader = [System.IO.BinaryReader]::new($readStream)

                $buffer = 512

                for($i = 0; $i -lt $file.Length; $i += $buffer) {
                    $bytes = $reader.ReadBytes($buffer)
                    $writer.Write($bytes)
                }
            } catch {
                Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
            } finally {
                $reader.Close()
                $reader.Dispose()
                $readStream.Close()
                $readStream.Dispose()
            }
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    } finally {
        $writer.Close()
        $writer.Dispose()
        $writeStream.Close()
        $writeStream.Dispose()
    }
}


###### test
$filePath = "C:\temp\some_test_file_here"
Split-File -InputPath $filePath -ChunkSize (1029*1022*43) -Zip

$item = Get-Item $filePath
$base = "$($item.BaseName)_*$($item.Extension)"


$files = Get-Item $base | select -ExpandProperty FullName
$recombinedPath = Join-Path $item.Directory "recombined_$($item.Name)"
Join-Files -Files $files -OutputPath $recombinedPath

Write-Host "Original hash: $((Get-FileHash $filePath).Hash)`tRecombined hash: $((Get-FileHash $recombinedPath).Hash)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
```